# Flutter: easy localization not updated for some page

Tags: flutter, localization

I added language options for my Flutter app. And I did this using easy localization. The problem is that while the page I change the language changes instantly, the page I return does not change. I am having a problem similar to the one in the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/fFOS5KXPHo8